# Alarm relay state check and email once if there is alarm

Tags: bash

This is my first bash script.

I have alarm relay and I want to check relay state every 2 minutes with cron and if it is "1", then email warning only once. I have to reset relay manually and I dont want to email every 2 minutes if the relay is "1".

It works but is there anything I can improve or do better way?

```
#!/bin/bash    
lockfile=/tmp/MLP_alarm.lock
alarm_state=$(/home/talo/bin/MLP_alarm_relay_state.py)

if [ $alarm_state = 0 -a -f $lockfile ]
then
   rm $lockfile
   echo "Alarm reset and lockfile removed"
   exit 1
elif [ $alarm_state = 0 -a ! -f $lockfile ]
then
   echo "Everything OK!"
   exit 1
elif [ $alarm_state = 1 -a ! -f $lockfile ]
then
   touch $lockfile
   echo “Alarm detected” | mail -s “ALARM !!!” me@email.com
   echo "email sent"
   exit 1
elif [ $alarm_state = 1 -a -f $lockfile ]
then
   echo "Email sent earlier"
   exit 1
else
   echo "Something went wrong!!!"
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `[ $alarm_state = 0 -a -f $lockfile ]`
   Is perfectlty okay but it is officially adviced to write that as
   `[ "$alarm_state" = "0" ] && [ -f "$lockfile" ]`
   because the -a option can be ambiguous in some cases.
2. Try to make it a habit to enclose all your variables (everything that begins with '$') with doublequotes. It will save you some headaches along the way (like for instance: filenames with spaces and such).

For the rest it looks perfect, there is not really anything to optimize here. :-)